# How do we replace PATH in all the files with an env variable

Tags: perl, shell

I have around 230 files which are *.pl , *.txt and some are *.conf files which has a default path set to the current environment say `/home/AD/USR/perl/5.8.0/bin/perl`. I need to replace `"/home/AD/USR"` with an environment variable `${USR_PATH}`. The files I want to modify are in subdirectories. Which means my script should find `e.g find .|xargs grep -l "/home/AD/USR"` all the files and then replace the string.

- OLD: `/home/AD/USR/perl/5.8.0/bin/perl`
- New : `${USR_PATH}/perl/5.8.0/bin/perl`

Can some one give me a clue how do I do that?

Shell : /bin/bash
Env : Linux x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace part of a string with `${USR_PATH}` you will refer to the perl variable `$USR_PATH`, not the environment variable, which is in perl referred to as `$ENV{USR_PATH}`.

```
perl -pi.bak -we 's#/home/AD/USR(?=/perl/5.8.0/bin/perl)#\$ENV{USR_PATH}#g' 
    *.pl *.txt *.conf
```

Using the lookahead will save you the trouble of replacing the rest of the path afterwards.

I assume you want to replace it with the literal value. If you want to replace it with the actual value in the environment variable, just remove the backslash in front of `$ENV`.

While using an environment variable seems handy and all, it will reduce your scripts portability. Why not use a configuration file? If you had done that from the start, you wouldn't be having this trouble. Search [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?q=config) for a nice module.

Comment: So, if `$ENV{USR_PATH} = "/foo/bar"`, does that mean you want the result to be `$ENV{USR_PATH}/perl/5.8.0/bin/perl` or `/foo/bar/perl/5.8.0/bin/perl`?

Comment: You are right about using conf. but the situation came up unwarrented and I had to find a workaround. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: /foo/bar/perl/5.8.0/bin/perl this is what i was expecting.

Comment: @dicaprio Then you'll need to remove the backslash, as mentioned in my answer. Though be aware that hard coding another path is just setting you up for a repeat of this same problem. The complete fix is to use a configuration file.

Comment: one question will this find the files only at the current directory?

Comment: @dicaprio Yes. You can use it with a xargs/find statement, though. Perl has its own recursive find module `File::Find`, but its a little clunky for a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

`perl -i -pe 's|/home/AD/USR/perl/5.8.0/bin/perl|\${USR_PATH}/perl/5.8.0/bin/perl|' <your files>`

Comment: I did try something similar. `perl -pi'*.bak' -e 's|^/home/AD/USR/|\${USR_PATH}|' `find ./ -name '*.conf'``. Not sure how to get this work. I need to search in subdirectories for the files having this path and replace.hope you got it?

Comment: Your script will not find the files which has the path /home/AD/USR.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question then. Are you trying to move files from one path to another, or are you trying to replace the path string within a bunch of text files?

Comment: I'm trying to find the files from the root dir which has the path /home/AD/USR and replace the path with the env variable.

Comment: e.g: find .|xargs grep -l "/home/AD/USR"

Comment: OK, so in those files, `/home/AD/USR` should be replaced with *the value* of `${USR_PATH}`? Then I say `perl -i -pe "s|/home/AD/USR|${USR_PATH}|" <your files>`

Comment: Yes in those files path should be replaced, but I need to find those files and then replace. Will your scripts find the files having mentioned path ?

Comment: I'm sorry I think you are right.I got it wrong in first place.Thank you.